# Collecting test suite time in aws device farm

Tags: aws-device-farm

I see we have the following time available in device farm aws console.

1. Setup Suite
2. Tests Suite
3. Teardown Suite

Is there a way we can visualize this ? Can I create a graph which shows the variations of teardown time across runs?

I am trying to use CloudTrail, but I don't see these details in any of the APIs. Can anyone help me understand how to collect these metrics and visualize them?